# NodeMCU (Lua) Parallel Timers

Tags: timer, lua, nodemcu

I'm quite a beginner and facing to an issue I can't solve for long time.

NodeMCU: 0.9.6 build 20150704
Lua: 5.1.4

********************* B1_up.lua ******************

```
Mpin = 8

gpio.mode(Mpin, gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.write(Mpin, gpio.HIGH)

xdf = 0
tmr.alarm(4, 1000, 1, function()
if xdf < 5 then xdf = xdf+ 1
else
gpio.write(Mpin, gpio.LOW)
tmr.stop(4)
end 
end)
```

---

********************* B2_up.lua ******************

```
Mpin = 0

gpio.mode(Mpin, gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.write(Mpin, gpio.HIGH)

xkf = 0
tmr.alarm(5, 1000, 1, function()
if xkf < 5 then xkf = xkf+ 1
else
gpio.write(Mpin, gpio.LOW)
tmr.stop(5)
end 
end)
```

---

Separately working fine each, BUT executing in sequence:

```
dofile("B1_up.lua")
dofile("B2_up.lua")
```

... only the last one (in this case B2_up.lua) executes the `gpio.write(Mpin, gpio.LOW)` command after 5 seconds. Why?

Comment: I don't know but that NodeMCU version is ancient and is no longer support. Try with a recent version: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/build/

Comment: @MarcelStör That version is the last version for certain hardware configurations.  Newer version may require newer hardware.  So the OP may be stuck to using this version.

Comment: "certain hardware configurations" - care to elaborate? If this about memory constraints (512KB) then there's the frozen 1.5.4.1 branch.

Comment: Thanks! However I don't think that it's a firmware issue, I tried to upgrade (e.g. 1.5.4.1), but the node (ESP 12 development board) don't work with any newer firmware. So I included the two timers to the main program instead of calling them as external functions. It works but not so elegant.